# Capture search url on click of search button in jquery/js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, post

How to capture the search url on click of search button before or in the interim of the form being submitted ?

The search url is getting embedded in the form action after the form is post and page is redirected to search results page.

Is there anyway I can capture the appended url in the interim ?

I am referring to a website similar to http://www.ramada.com.

On ramada.com,on click of the "find it" button,the user inputs are passed through a js and gets embedded a form action via POST.On this button,only I want the url to be captured using jquery serialise or any other way.

This is the button :

```
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn_prim find_it" tabindex="135" value="Find it" name="searchSubView:findIt" id="searchSubView:findIt">
```

This is the form which appears in the search-results page:

```
    <form id="SearchResultForm" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="/hotels/united-kingdom/london/search-results?partner_id=&Available_property=false&campaign_code=&checkout_date=07%2F31%2F2013&children=0&useWRPoints=false&ratePlan=BAR&teens=0&affiliate_id=&searchWithinMiles=&PriceFilter=0-2147483647&perpage=15&brand_code=BH%2CDI%2CRA%2CBU%2CHJ%2CKG%2CMT%2CSE%2CTL%2CWG%2CWY%2CPX%2CWT%2CWP%2CPN&content=false&iata=&adults=1&checkin_date=07%2F30%2F2013&radius=25&rooms=1" method="post" name="SearchResultForm">
```

Comment: I don't quite follow. Could you post some code?

Comment: You can use jQuery or JavaScript to change the URL onsubmit.

Comment: Fiddler might do the trick, if I can guess what it is you are really trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by dynamically setting the value of the action attribute in form tag.

When page loads you load it with

```
<form action="">
```

Then add a on click handler to the Search button.

```
var searchUrl = "website.com/path/to/action?parameters"
$("#searchSubView:findIt").click(function () {
     $("#SearchResultForm").attr("action",searchUrl);
});
```

This if you want to dynamically set the action url for the form.

But if you just want to find out where the form request was sent to, you can use Fiddler as David had said.

Or you can use the developer tools in Chrome, or Firebug in firefox. In these tools check the network request tab, and you will find the form submit url with header and body details of the request.

Comment: Actually I want to capture the url,on the homepage only and not on the search-results page.Your solution holds good only after I have reached search-results page,when the url already has the desired parameters.

Comment: you want to capture the url the page is redirecting to from the home page after the redirection has started?

Comment: It needs to be done before the search results page is loaded.

Comment: taking the ramada.com example. You click on Find It on home page and it takes you to search results page. So the above code needs to be on your home page for the form which submits the parameters for the search results. i.e. the on click of the "Find It" button.

Comment: In the homepage,the 'searchUrl' is still not formed.It gets created after the form is post.

Comment: In that case you cannot get it at the javascript side. this url is created based on the form post at the server side as a redirect. hence you can get it only at the server or by watching the network requests either through tools like chrome devtools or firebug or Fiddler, etc..